# Create a matrix with A(i, j) = i*j

Tags: matlab, matrix

I was practicing a Cody Problem:

> At one time or another, we all had to memorize boring times tables. 5 times 5 is 25. 5 times 6 is 30. 12 times 12 is way more than you think.
>
> With MATLAB, times tables should be easy! Write a function that outputs times tables up to the size requested.

I solved it with the code below.

```
function m = timestables(n)
for i =1:n
    for j = 1:n
        m(i,j) = i*j;
    end
end
end
```

Could I write it without `for` cycles and improve my score?

It may look stupid, but it is also useful for my work.

Comment: The challenge you are linking is locked for people who aren't working on the Cody challenge / don't have a high enough score there. Please consider adding the question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [**`ndgrid`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) it's an easy task.

```
[x,y] = ndgrid(1:n)
m = x.*y
```

Alternatively use [**`bsxfun`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), probably fastest solution, as `bsxfun` is always the fastest ;):

```
m = bsxfun(@times,1:n,(1:n).')
```

Comment: I had read about `bsxfun`, but never used it before, when I tried I was missing the `.'` so it only gave me the diagonal 1 4 9 16 25. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

if it is a minimum-length answer you're after, you might want to consider:

```
m = [1:n]'*[1:n];
```

But I suspect the `bsxfun` and `ndgrid` solutions thewaywewalk proposed are more efficient in terms of computation time.

Answer (score 5):

The simpler the better ; multiply the vectors:

```
m = (1:n)'*(1:n);
```

Best,